# Solving a system of PDEs using implicit methods

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, differential-equations, pde

I've got a system of partial differential equations (PDEs), specifically the diffusion-advection-reaction-equation applied to heat transfer and convection, which I solve using finite difference method.
In my simulation environment I've got a multitude of different parts, like pipes, energy storages, heat exchangers etc... Depending on the part, each part's PDE can be 1D (as in most cases) or 2D (about 5% of the parts) or 3D (seldom). Because of these different shapes constructing a tridiagonal (or penta-, septa-...) for the whole system is too complicated.
This question is posted here on SO and not on computational science, since it is about **how to use solving algorithms for PDEs** and not about solving-methods for PDEs.

Thus currently each part has a `diff` function, which returns its differential for the given input temperatures. Since material properties etc. are temperature (and flow) dependant, the PDEs are non-linear, but considered as linear by *lagging the coefficients* (calculating temperature and flow dependent values with the start temperature at each step and for implicit methods recalculating them at each iteration). The **shape of the differentials returned by the `diff` function is the same as the part's value array shape**, for example for a 1D pipe with 10 grid points this results in an differential array of shape `(10, )`. **Diffusion coefficients and other coefficients are considered as internal to the `diff` function and will not be available to the solver. So the solver will only know the differential, the current part temperature and the stepsize.**

Is there any way to solve these PDEs in python **only one step at a time** using an algorithm which is dedicated to solving PDEs? (And an algorithm which is preferably part of `scipy/numpy` and even more preferably already supported by `numba`.)
Things I have considered so far:

- `scipy.integrate`: Only feasible for ODEs, whereas a PDE may not be covered by this. Is that correct? At least I can't get good results with it for PDEs. Besides that `scipy.integrate` is not made for calculating only one single step.
- `np.linalg.solve`: Seems like the best way to go, if you have tri-diagonal matrices with linear equations. But since I neither have tri-diagonal matrices, nor linear equations (linearized, but lagging the coefficients means having to update them during iterations). Is there any way to still use this without too much computational cost?
- `scipy.optimize`: Feasible and easy to use. My minimum working example below will integrate a solution using this. But will this **always** work for PDEs **and is this generally a correct way to solve PDEs implicitly or is this just working in this example and I am on the wrong track?**
- Own integration of a simple iterative function. Also shown in the example below. Same as with `scipy.optimize`: Is this just working in this simple example or will this work for PDEs in general?

### Minimum working example

```
import time
from scipy import optimize

def diff(T):  # simply example differential function
    time.sleep(0.0001)  # dummy timer to slow down the calculation
    return np.sqrt(T)

def euler_bdf(y, yprev, h):
    return (y - yprev - h*diff(y))

def crank_nicolson(y, yprev, h):  # diff(yprev) will be outsourced for performance
    return (y - yprev - h / 2 * (diff(y) + diff(yprev)))

def iterate_eulerbdf(y0, h, rtol, diff):
    y = y0
    f = np.ones_like(y)
    i = 0
    while np.any(f > rtol):
        y_old = y
        y = y0 + h * diff(y)
        f = (y / y_old - 1)  # this will be replaced by least mean squares
        i += 1
    return y, i

def iterate_cranknicolson(y0, h, rtol, diff):
    y = y0
    diff_old = diff(y)
    f = np.ones_like(y)
    i = 0
    while np.any(f > rtol):
        y_old = y
        y = y0 + h / 2 * (diff_old + diff(y))
        f = (y / y_old - 1)
        i += 1
    return y, i

T0 = np.arange(10, 20).astype(float)  # starting temperature

eulerbdf_hybr = optimize.root(euler_bdf, T0, args=(T0, 1.), method='hybr', tol=1e-6)
eulerbdf_dfsane = optimize.root(euler_bdf, T0, args=(T0, 1.), method='df-sane', tol=1e-6)
eulerbdf_it = iterate_eulerbdf(T0, 1., 1e-6, diff)

cn_hybr = optimize.root(crank_nicolson, T0, args=(T0, 1.), method='hybr', tol=1e-6)
cn_dfsane = optimize.root(crank_nicolson, T0, args=(T0, 1.), method='df-sane', tol=1e-6)
cn_it = iterate_cranknicolson(T0, 1., 1e-6, diff)
```

**TL,DR summary of the question**

All of the results seem to be ok, but is this approach ok for *real* PDEs in general?
Which is the recommended way to do it?
Which is the most performant way to do it for a wide variety of PDEs of different shapes and sizes, ranging from `(5,)` to more than `(100, 100, 100)`? For `scipy.integrate` currently `'df-sane'` seems to be the fastest, but I doubt this will be true for larger problems.
And especially: **Is there any better way to do this?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, even the summary is too broad in my opinion.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Shouldn't a summary be broad? But what can I improve? I wanted to avoid writing down the discretizations of the PDEs. Would that help? @uhoh: That's where I posted my last questions considering this topic, but I thought this may be more appropriate for SO, since it involves solving algorithms implemented in `scipy/numpy`.

Comment: For PDE's the first port of call is always separation of variables with pen and paper.

Comment: @PaulaThomas Yep, but this is for a simulation environment where this is not feasible, since it solves several million steps. Just having non-linear coefficients would also make this quite much impossible with pen and paper.